# Stars and Bars with unique partitions

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if there is a function to find the number of combinations for k bars and n stars, with the restriction that each partition is unique. For example (with three stars and one bar), `f(3, 1) = 1` because

x | x x = (1, 2)

x x | x = (2, 1) which is just a reflection of (1, 2)

Therefore, there is one unique partition. However, the proper stars and bars function would return 2 since 2 choose 1 is 2.

Comment: Stars and bars does not count this.  You are looking for *Partition Numbers* instead, and specifically *Restricted* partition numbers, restricted in number of parts and uniqueness of partsize.  There is no easy closed form, however there is an easy generating function: $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty (1+qx^i)$, and look at the coefficient of the $q^kx^n$ term in the expansion.

Comment: Thanks! @JMoravitz

Comment: It is not clear precisely what you are looking for, but presumably one of [OEIS A008284](https://oeis.org/A008284) or [OEIS A008289](https://oeis.org/A008289) or [OEIS A216652](https://oeis.org/A216652)

Comment: Will take a look at these also. Thanks @Henry for sending

Comment: If you want to split $6$ into $3$ unique parts ($2$ bars), how many would you get in your question? Three $(4+1+1,3+2+1,2+2+2)$ or one $(3+2+1)$ or six $(3+2+1,3+1+2,2+3+1,2+1+3,1+3+2,1+2+3)$?

Comment: The answer would be 3 since those are the three distinct groupings of stars after placing the bars @Henry

Comment: Then you want [OEIS A008284](https://oeis.org/A008284) the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ positive parts (or perhaps $k+1$ positive parts if you use using $k$ bars, but this would be unconventional)